# How can I output 3 sets of info in a specific order for each set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have performed a bunch of analysis on some client data and want to present the duplicates that I found across their systems.

I match on based on 4 separate criteria, Name, Address (multiple addresses and lines) and Phone (every phone number associated with the account) and Email (every email associated with the account).

I boil it all down into a single table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dupe_Customers](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MatchOn] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [DataID] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [CustName] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Address] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Phone] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Fax] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](255) NULL
)
```

When I present it, I want view it in a specific order and ordering within each dataset.

```
SELECT * FROM [dupe_Customers] WHERE [MatchOn] = 'Name' ORDER BY [CustName]

SELECT * FROM [dupe_Customers] WHERE [MatchOn] = 'Address' ORDER BY [Address]

SELECT * FROM [dupe_Customers] WHERE [MatchOn] = 'Phone' ORDER BY [Phone]

SELECT * FROM [dupe_Customers] WHERE [MatchOn] = 'Email' ORDER BY [Email]
```

If I use a `UNION` I of course can't use the `ORDER BY` and have to pick a single ordering for the entire dataset... Which defeats the purpose since I can just do that on the table as a whole already.
I know I can just output 4 diff times, but the goal is to have a single output so it can be loaded on a single tab in Excel.  (If you know how to output multiple datasets to a single tab in Excel I'd love to know how to do that!)

The only thing I can think of is to put each into a new table with an id, something like:

```
SELECT identity (int,1,1) as [id], * INTO newTable FROM [dupe_Customers] WHERE [MatchOn] = 'Name' ORDER BY [CustName]

INSERT INTO newTable
  SELECT * FROM [dupe_Customers] WHERE [MatchOn] = 'Address' ORDER BY [Address]
```

Then I'd just do a `SELECT * FROM newTable ORDER BY [id]`

In addition to feeling "hacky" I am not 100% confident that the data is actually inserted into the new table in the correct order.

This is about a midsize data set with about 500k rows.  I am using Azure and it is 3-5x slower than when I was doing things on my local machine, so I'd like to avoid something too processor intensive that's going to take hours to run.

Comment: Use a `CASE` expression to build your `ORDER BY` clause such that it orders as you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may order using a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [dupe_Customers]
WHERE [MatchOn] IN ('Name', 'Address', 'Phone', 'Email')
ORDER BY [MatchOn],
         CASE [MatchOn]
         WHEN 'Name' THEN CustName
         WHEN 'Address' THEN Address
         WHEN 'Phone' THEN Phone
         WHEN 'Email' THEN Email END;
```

Comment: That's probably as close as I'm going to get.  It orders each dataset as I wanted, it just doesn't have [MatchOn] in the order I want (Name, Address, Phone, Email), it has them alphabetical.